# LARAVEL: Trying to insert Optional Value 'Image' to Server

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

i am quite new to Laravel and was creating a social media website as practice where users update their status like the facebook thing but the issue am having is that its not every post that should have an image attached to it.

So when ever i send a post without an image it gives me this error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `stories` (`body`, `image`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (My anme os Ololade, , 2, 2017-12-14 14:00:08, 2017-12-14 14:00:08))

Which shows that there is no value for the image. However, i updated the migration file and made the image nullable like this: 
$table->binary('image')->nullable();
It works and image upload becomes optional but on checking my sql database i do not get to see a blob file whenever i upload images as all values under the image column is null.

Please is there a way to override this error laravel gives me? That is: If there is no image, it should go ahead and update status or if i could pass a validation via my controller that the image data is not required.

here is my code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->text('body');
            $table->binary('image')->
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

//Migrations file




    public function createStory(Request $request){
            $image  = $request['image'];
            $story = new Story();
            $story->body = $request['body'];
            $story->image = $image;
            $request->user()->stories()->save($story);
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Your Story has been posted']);
        }

    //The Function that creates a post
```

Comment: You need to add condition first before executing the query to check whether image is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel for getting request image file, then you will code like follwing.

```
$image = $request->file("image");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn`t $image($request['image']). 
etc there is not POST variable image.

You may set image field in story table that allows null like following.

ALTER TABLE `story` CHANGE `image` `image` BLOB NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Column 'image' cannot be null issue is coming when you are not passing image from your form but executing in query every time.

For resolving this issue, you can either allow NULL for image in database or you have to add condition with `$request->hasFile` to insert image only if its coming like below:

```
        $image  = $request['image'];
        $story = new Story();
        $story->body = $request['body'];
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $story->image = $image;
        }
        $story->save();
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, My Reputation level is low.. I cant mark your answer as the correct one

Comment: You can mark it even if your reputation is low. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: You can even upvote any answer as your reputation is not that much low. Also you will get 2 points when you accept any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `image` column keep getting null values should be this line:

```
$image = $request['image'];
```

What does your `$request['image']` return? Is it a string? Or a file? If it is the latter, you should make a copy of that file and store it somewhere, then save the `path` to your `image` column.